# how full disable gitlab oidc well-known tls with helm in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

### Description:

I installed Gitlab using Helm in an Intranet environment. According to the Gitlab documentation, I have disabled the TLS configuration. Only HTTP access is enabled on the ingress. Access to Gitlab page content, everything is fine.

When I visited the `well-known` page of OIDC on Gitlab, the prompt of the issuer was HTTP, but it was HTTPS for the other addresses.

Of course, I know that when using IDC-IDP, you can ignore certificate verification. However, for some applications this option is not provided at integration time, so authentication fails.

I want to know what configuration I need to adjust so that the well-known addresses are all HTTP. Of course, it is better to be able to adjust through the helm.

### env

- gitlab helm chart version: `6.9.1`
- gitlab version: `15.9.1-ee`

### snapshot

**expected:**

```json
{
    "issuer": "http://gitlab.example.com",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/token",
    "revocation_endpoint": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/revoke",
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/introspect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/userinfo",
    "jwks_uri": "http://gitlab.example.com/oauth/discovery/keys",
    "scopes_supported": [
        "api",
        "read_api",
......
```

**acturally:**

```json
{
    "issuer": "http://gitlab.example.com",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/token",
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/revoke",
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/introspect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/userinfo",
    "jwks_uri": "https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/discovery/keys",
    "scopes_supported": [
        "api",
        "read_api",
......
```

Comment: Have you considered doing tls passthrough for this endpoint instead of trying to disable tls?